# statistics- probability

Tags: statistics

Suppose a community of 10 members want to build a bridge. Each member can either contribute 100 dollars or nothing. The probability that a single member of the community contribute to the construction of the bridge is 0.65. Assuming that each member’s decision to contribute is independent of the other members’ decisions to contribute, what is the probability that the bridge IS built if building the bridge costs 700 dollars?

can i use the fact:

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)?$$  I am confused with this tricky problem. please help

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:You are looking for $$P(x \geq 7) = P(7)+P(8) + P(9) + P(10) = \binom{10}{7}0.65^7\cdot 0.35^3+ ...$$

Comment: is this because 7 people makes $700?

Comment: why can't I just use x=7?

Comment: If more than $7$ persons voted to build it ?

Comment: oh i get it! :) thanks a lot for your brilliance!